# Python Dictionary cannot find key

Tags: python

I'm having difficulty with a script where it is not finding a key that is actually present inside the dictionary. Here's code snippet in question

```
#print( str( type( UsedGunInventoryItems ) ) )
#print( str( UsedGunInventoryItems ) )
#print( str( UsedGunInventoryItems['174746'] ) )    <-------------THIS LINE WORKS PERFECTLY

if( type( UsedGunInventoryItems ) is dict ):
    for CSVUsedGunItemNumber in CSV_Used_Guns:
        CSVUsedGunItemNumber = CSVUsedGunItemNumber.strip()
        if( not CSVUsedGunItemNumber == "" ):

            #check if the current item number exists in the current inventory
            #if( CSVUsedGunItemNumber in UsedGunInventoryItems.keys() ):    <-------- THIS DOES NOT FIND THE KEY
            UsedGunFound = UsedGunInventoryItems.get( CSVUsedGunItemNumber ) <-------- THIS DOES NOT FIND THE KEY
            if( UsedGunFound ):
```

Item Number `174746` DOES exist in `CSVUsedGunItemNumber` and is being hit in the loop

Not sure what I can do to fix this issue.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to trace ti line by line?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: In the line that works, the key you use is actually a string. Any chance that `CSVUsedGunItemNumber` is an `int` instead?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that while the script is running.  I'm used to C# where you can debug as its running

Comment: @joeb you can debug python while it is running, for example with PyCharm

Comment: @SimonCrane or with the python debugger...

Comment: Or simply by adding print statements.

Comment: @Lagerbaer shouldn't the strip() function convert it to string?

Comment: @joeb no, `strip()` will return a *new string* from another string, but doesn't not change types (indeed, an `int` would throw an `AttributeError`). Again, though, you need to provide a [mcve] or else this is off-topic

Comment: But, `UsedGunInventoryItems.get( CSVUsedGunItemNumber )` is **not how you check if a key is in a dict**. So, for example, the value retrieved may be falsy. To check if a key is in a dictionary you simply use `some_key in some_dict`.

Comment: This is what is inside UsedGunInventoryItems `u'174746': {'PostID': 23357, 'Modified': datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 2, 9, 42, 42), 'Stock': u'0'}`

Comment: @joeb **that is not a [mcve]**. Please provide one.

Comment: I can let you teamviewer in.  There's too much surrounding code to post here

Comment: And this script works for 99% of the dict.  Seems this one item is a problem

Comment: @joeb No. That isn't what is required of you. You **need to provide a [mcve]** or else this question is *off-topic*.

Comment: I just figured it out.  Turns out the incoming data was bad.  The script is working as intended.  Thanks for all the help anyways

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will find it if the type does not match.  You are asking it for a number with type of string ('174746').  Is is possible the dictionary was constructed with keys of type int?

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of of something like `print CSVUsedGunItemNumber`?  Is it a string?  Does it have the correct value.  If your comment at the top is correct then the value `'174746'` is in there.  What you're trying to access with is not

Additionally your code can even "fail" when it is in there.  For example the following dictionary won't take you into the `if` block that you want it to

```
x = {'174746': False}
```

Then `x.get('174746')` will return `False` obviously.  So it is in the dictionary and found, but your `UsedGunFound` variable will be `False` which is misleading at best

Comment: Okay...what is the VALUE of the string?  Have you tried stepping through with a debugger (or even a basic print statement)